# Can't start ListActivity via Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, listactivity

I have 2 activities. First activity extends `Activity` and second extends `ListActivity`.

I need to call `ListActivity` from the `Activity` class

I have tried the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(firstclassname.this, secongclassname.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

I've added an entry in the manifest file but it doen't work.

That same code works for the Activity class (if the second class extends `ListActivity`)

I got following Logcat output

```
04-26 15:51:48.235: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=android.com.testHTML/.FindFilesByType }
04-26 15:51:48.395: ERROR/ArrayAdapter(3113): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
04-26 15:51:48.395: WARN/dalvikvm(3113): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
04-26 15:51:48.405: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1273)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1658)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1516)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1112)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1108)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:920)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:979)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1613)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
04-26 15:51:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3113):     ... 30 more
04-26 15:51:48.436: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 3113 SIG: 3
04-26 15:51:48.446: INFO/dalvikvm(3113): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-26 15:51:48.446: ERROR/dalvikvm(3113): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
04-26 15:51:58.289: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-26 15:51:58.289: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4391c898 android.com.testHTML/.FindFilesByType}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just make sure, you dont have any problem in ListActivity's onCreate()...

Comment: add your code of listactivity..

Comment: public class FindFilesByType extends ListActivity {

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  
  tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ringtone);

  ListView lv = getListView();
  File ringtones_directory = new File(DIRECTORY);
  if (!ringtones_directory.exists()) {

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(
     FindFilesByType.this);
   ad.setTitle("Directory Not Found");
   ad.setMessage("Sorry! The ringtones directory doesn't exist.");
   ad.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
   ad.show();
   hasErrors = true;
  }

Comment: if (!ringtones_directory.canRead()) {
   AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(
     FindFilesByType.this);
   ad.setTitle("Permissions");
   ad.setMessage("Sorry! You don't have permission to list the files in that folder");
   ad.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
   ad.show();
   hasErrors = true;
  }
  else {
   Ringtones = FindFiles(false);

   if (Ringtones.size() < 1) {
    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(
      FindFilesByType.this);
    ad.setTitle("Permissions");
    ad.setMessage("Sorry! No ringtones

Comment: if (!hasErrors) {
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, R.layout.main,
     Ringtones));
   
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View v,
      int position, long id) {
     currentPosition = position;
     playRingtone(DIRECTORY+Ringtones.get(position));
    }
   });
  }
 }

Comment: http://androidworkz.com/2010/07/08/source-code-find-files-by-type-play-media-file/ this is my code into the ListActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity is properly started.

The problem is in [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) that you are using. You are not providing the resource id of the `TextView`.

Check out which constructor you are using and provide the correct parameters.